# Libgdx - Instead of create(), dispose() is called first

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new to libgdx based android games. I have noticed that the dispose() is called when I start the game and then the create method is called. This causes several issues in my game.
Please let me know how to avoid this.

```
public void create() {    
    System.out.println("StartScreen - create");
}

public void dispose() {   
    System.out.println("StartScreen - dispose");
}
```

Comment: Debug in the dispose method and check from where it is getting called.

Comment: Could you please show us what else you have in your class, or other class files.
Because it appears that somewhere before the class your code is from, is calling the dispose method of that class instead of its own.
According to https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses, > "dispose() is never called automaticly"